# Apollo Server - Selectively return array members based on children

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-server

I'm using Node.js Apollo Server (4.3.0) to return fairly complex GraphQL. Greatly simplified here, I have an `Connection` of `Child` objects that can be queried directly, as well as a `Connection` of `Parent` objects that can contain the same `ChildConnection`.

```
type Query {
  parentQuery(first: Int, after: String): ParentConnection
  childQuery(first: Int, after: String): ChildConnection
}

type ParentConnection: {
  edges: [ParentEdge!]
  pageInfo: PageInfo
}
type ParentEdge: {
  node: Parent
  cursor: String
}
type Parent: {
  children(first: Int, after: String): ChildConnection
}

type ChildConnection: {
  edges: [ChildEdge!]
  pageInfo: PageInfo
}
type ChildEdge: {
  node: Child
  cursor: String
}
type Child {
  id: ID!
}
```

The issue arises when calling `parentQuery`, asking for the whole tree. Sometimes the `children` field for a particular `Parent` has no edges, and is not useful to send to a client. I would like to omit this `ParentEdge` from the query response, rather than stripping it on the client-side which seems wasteful and error-prone.

In Apollo server this would usually be fine - call directly down to your resolver tree, await the results, return null for the parent or simply don't add it to the Connection. The complication here is that the `ChildConnection` takes the usual `Connection` args, and in Apollo Server, the args for a child are not available to the parent. Thus, attempting to resolve the tree from the `ParentConnection` level will ignore the `ChildConnection` args. Attempting to resolve the tree from the `Parent` level, at most allows you to modify the `ParentEdge` resolver via the `parent` field, leaving you with empty entries in the `ParentConnection.edges` field.

Hoisting the args from the `children` field of the `Parent` to the `parentQuery` would solve the problem, but it would be designing the schema to match the implementation, rather than following connection best-practices.

The two clean solutions in my mind are:

1. Having a way for a parent resolver to get access to its children's args, or
2. Having a way in to perform processing on a resolver AFTER its entire tree has been resolved. Even potentially after the entire query has been completed.